# Unable to run MongoDB as a Service in RHEL 8

Tags: linux, systemd, mongodb, rhel8

`systemctl start mongod` Doesn't appear to do anything.
`systemctl status mongod` shows no changes.
`journal -xeu mongod.service` is empty.

`mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf` starts MongoDB successfully.

systemd service file.  */usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
After=multi-user.target
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
Type=forking
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false
# Recommended limits for for mongod as specified in
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Why Doesn't MongoDB Start as a service, and how can I fix it?

**Update:**

Status output

```
# systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
```

I installed **MongoDB** with **Yum** by adding a new repository

```
# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.0.repo
[mongodb-org-4.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use RHEL 7 packages on RHEL 8. This isn't going to work.

Comment: It originally did.  And then I ran into some issues after an unintended hard reboot.  I tried to completely wipe and re-install MongoDB but that didn't help at all.